# JSF <p:separator> leaves much space at the top and at its bottom

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have set of labels and textfields which are displayed one below the other for example

```
    LABEL1 
    LABEL2
    LABEL3
    LABEL4
```

I separated them by a separator  like this

```
    LABEL1 
    LABEL2
    ----------
    LABEL3
    LABEL4
```

The problem that separator leave space at it top and the bottom.Like the one shown below

[image]

 If you see the above, you can see the space between project category & separator & project manager systems are high.
I am trying to reduce the space between the label and the seperator.

The code the I have used for separator is

```
<tr><td><p:separator style="width:450px"></td></tr>
```

All the labels and the separator are inside the `<table></table>`.

I used this code

```
<tr><td><p:separator style="width:450px;vertical-align:top;height:1px" /></td>
                            </tr>
```

and the seperator got aligned below the top label without space but the label below the separator has the same space which is shown below 
[image]

Please advise me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the margin/padding in the style property of your separator?

Comment: I just posted the code that I am using for the separator;padding did not worked out!!

Comment: What about the padding of the parent element? Try to modify it using Firebug

Comment: Not just the padding of the td; also min-height and such. By the way, I'm not too familiar with Primefaces; what HTML element does `p:separator` resolve to?